# Ruby - Extract a string from a line in array and place it at the start of the following lines

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm working on log files and I need to copy a string from a line and copy it to the start of the next line... Please help [new to Ruby & Regex]

here is my input

```
18:07:12 grd TIMESTAMP 2/2/2014
12:19:24   IN A2010 drosa SA400583
12:19:24   IN A2010 dsrosa SA456583
0:07:26 grd TIMESTAMP 2/3/2014
22:19:24   IN A2010 dosa SA400583
22:10:21   IN A2010 dsrosa SA456583
```

I wanted to take the date i.e. `2/2/2014` and place it at the start of the following lines until it found the next time stamp i.e. `2/3/2014` ... Expected output is

```
2/2/2014 12:19:24   IN A2010 drosa SA400583
2/2/2014 12:19:24   IN A2010 dsrosa SA456583
2/3/2014 22:19:24   IN A2010 dosa SA400583
2/3/2014 22:10:21   IN A2010 dsrosa SA456583
```

Please help. Cheers

Comment: You output doesn't include `2/3/2014` - is that a mistake?

Comment: oops.. yep.. forgot to change the date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable#slice_before`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before) to find chunks starting with a specific pattern:

```
input = <<EOD.lines
18:07:12 grd TIMESTAMP 2/2/2014
12:19:24   IN A2010 drosa SA400583
12:19:24   IN A2010 dsrosa SA456583
0:07:26 grd TIMESTAMP 2/3/2014
22:19:24   IN A2010 dosa SA400583
22:10:21   IN A2010 dsrosa SA456583
EOD

input.slice_before(/TIMESTAMP/).each do |first_line, *other_lines|
  timestamp = first_line[/\d+\/\d+\/\d+/]
  other_lines.each do |line|
    puts "#{timestamp} #{line}"
  end
end
```

Output:

```
2/2/2014 12:19:24   IN A2010 drosa SA400583
2/2/2014 12:19:24   IN A2010 dsrosa SA456583
2/3/2014 22:19:24   IN A2010 dosa SA400583
2/3/2014 22:10:21   IN A2010 dsrosa SA456583
```

I've used `/TIMESTAMP/` (lines containing the word `TIMESTAMP`) as the pattern, `/grd/` would work, too. The actual timestamp (`2/2/2014`) is extracted from each first line using [`String#[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-5B-5D). Note that `input` is an array.

Comment: hi, sorry stephen ... I've put the  two '*' infront to make the start lines as bold ... apologies.   I've updated my question now...

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly. The regular expressions are flexible enough to work with and without extra characters.